# How to change clicked item glyphicon

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

am binding list of products from database in my page with icon,
initially am showing glyphicon off for all items , when i click list item am changing clicked item glyphicon to ok,
but if i select any other item in list first item glyphicon changing to ok , i want to change icon of clicked item

my code is
view

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="myNavbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li ng-repeat="prod in products">
                                    <a href="#" id="{{prod.ID}}" class="productClass" ng-click="getModules($event)">{{prod.PRODCTNAME}}<span id="iProduct"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-off ChangeButtonColorOrangeRed"></span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

js

```
 $scope.getModules = function (event) {
        var prodID = event.target.id;
        var productElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#iProduct'));
        productElement.toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-off ChangeButtonColorOrangeRed').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok ChangeButtonColorGreen');
        var moduleDiv = angular.element(document.querySelector('#divModule'));
        moduleDiv.toggleClass('divProductsHide').toggleClass('divProductsShow');
        productService.getModules(prodID).then(function (d) {
            $scope.modules = d.data;
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Error!');
        });

    };
```

css

```
<style>
    .ChangeButtonColorOrangeRed {
        color: orangered;
    }

    .ChangeButtonColorGreen {
        color: green;
    }
```

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/moncef_hbey/HB7LU/17481/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get selected Item by using this example below.Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kj0xxgcPUqFRCcQ26Rb0?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<body data-ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-repeat="prod in products">
          <a href="#"  class="productClass" ng-click="selectProduct(prod.id)">{{prod.name}}  
          <span data-ng-hide="selectedProducts.indexOf(prod.id) > -1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-off ChangeButtonColorOrangeRed"></span>
          <span data-ng-show="selectedProducts.indexOf(prod.id) > -1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok ChangeButtonColorGreen"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("myApp",[]);

angular.module("myApp").controller("myController",function($scope){

  $scope.products = [
    {id:1,name:'A'},
    {id:2,name:'B'},
    {id:3,name:'C'}
    ];

  $scope.selectedProducts = [];

  $scope.selectProduct = function(id){

    var index = $scope.selectedProducts.indexOf(id);

    if(index > -1){
      $scope.selectedProducts.splice(index,1);
    }else{
      $scope.selectedProducts.push(id);
    }

  }

})
```

**Update**

Change this function for selecting only one product

```
$scope.selectProduct = function(id){

   $scope.selectedProducts= [id];

}
```

Comment: Thank you Aravinthon its working, but i want to change only clicked item icon to ok ,remaining all item to off

Comment: not working Aravinthon , glyphicon not changing if i use this

Comment: am not seeing any update Aravinthon , i think plunker not updated

Comment: I have updated again. Please check(https://plnkr.co/edit/Kj0xxgcPUqFRCcQ26Rb0?p=preview)

Comment: Hi aravinthon,am binding this list horizontally in my page , i want to this list as slider how to apply styles for this, can you please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class to solve this problem.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-repeat="prod in products" ng-init="off=false">
            <a href="#" id="{{prod.ID}}" class="productClass" ng-click="off=!off">{{prod.PRODCTNAME}}<span id="iProduct"  ng-class="off?'change-button-to-green':'change-button-to-red'"></span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.change-button-to-red {
        color: orangered;
}

.change-button-to-green {
        color: green;
}
```

This will solve problem.

Comment: Thanks sai for responding ,on ng-click am binding another list in my view how to handle both click events

Comment: You can call both in that using `;` seperation.

Comment: how to change only clicked item icon to ok ,remaining all item to off

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in selection:

```
 var productElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#iProduct'));
```

You are selecting value with id '#iProduct'. So query selector pick the first match and change the class of the first span.

So, provide dynamic id to span also.
I added a fiddle for this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ranageneration/s5ua3fed/